# Laravel Mail::queue not async

Tags: php, laravel, queue, beanstalkd

I have a problem with laravel 5.1 queues. 
I have beanstalkd already set up in my Homestead vm so all i did was to change the queue driver from the `default` one to `beanstalkd` in `config/queue.php`. I've tried the code below and neither one seem to be queued. They all fired synchronously, as soon as i run the code. I didn't even fire the `artisan queue:listen` command. What am i doing wrong?

```
Route::get('/', function () {
//    return view('welcome');

    Queue::push(function($job)
    {
        Log::info("Dadas");
        $job->delete();
    });

    $input = [
        'name' => 'Mario Bašić',
        'email' => 'email@me.com',
        'comment' =>  'Testing queues',
        'subject' =>  'Email subject'
    ];

    Mail::queue('emails.test', $input, function($message) use ($input)
    {
        $message->to($input['email'], $input['name']);
        $message->subject($input['subject']);
        Log::info('sending');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you change the driver in the `.env` file:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd
```

Changing the value in the `config/queue.php` to:

```php
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'beanstalkd'),
```

won't work if another value is set for `QUEUE_DRIVER` in `.env`.